# Cannot apply operator "||" of type "bool" and "Vector2"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, collider

im kinda new to programming.I need some help,im making a code where whenever i press on the asset of a specific collider size it gets destroyed,but im having some trouble making that,this is the code that i currently have!!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class destroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BoxCollider2D box;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        box = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        box.isTrigger = true;
        box.size = new Vector2(1, 1);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if(box.isTrigger || box.size) 
            
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }


        }


    }

}
```

The error is Cannot apply operator "||" of type "bool" and "Vector2",i know whats the problem but I cant solve it...

Comment: What does the condition `box.isTrigger || box.size` mean to you? More specifically, how do you think that `box.size` is `true` or `false`? How can a size be a boolean value?

Comment: I know that box.size cant be true or false i want the box.isTrigger to work only at this specific box.size which is (1, 1),i dont know if i explained it any better,if you didnt understand i can explain what im trying to do,its basically when you click on an asset in the range of the collider it gets destroyed,but if not in range,nothing happens to the object.

Comment: Try saying your if statement in English: "If the box's "isTrigger" is true, and the box's size is ..., then destroy the game object ". Fill in the blank.

Comment: It sounds like the OP want to destroy the object when the mouse is in the bounds of the box.

Comment: @kaskifx - Please also learn the difference between a `,` and a `.` when you write. It's hard to understand your sentences with commas everywhere.

Comment: If what you want is to check that `box.size` is equal to a specific value then that's what you need to do. What you've done is like a bartender checking someone's age, but not comparing it to the legal drinking age to see whether they can be served alcohol. You need to actually do a comparison and it's the comparison that will be true or false.

Answer (score 2):

Besides as mentioned your condition not making much sense - there is a built-in message for this that already handles this: [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)

> OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the Collider.

So this code

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

is really all you need.

[image]

---

Then **if** the `BoxCollider2D` really is a **trigger**

> This function is called on Colliders and 2D Colliders marked as trigger when the following properties are set to true:
>
> - For 2D physics: Physics2D.queriesHitTriggers

I think you actually misinterpreted what `box.isTrigger` is and does exactly: There are two types of colliders in Unity

- Non-Trigger: A physical solid collider which actively participates in the physics and collides and thereby influences other object's movement
- Trigger: A collider that does NOT physically interact with other objects but is only used to receive or cause events

so this property defines how this collider should act - it does NOT tell you anything about a state regarding your interaction in terms of "has been triggered".

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector2?view=net-7.0) about Vector2. Vector is not a BOOLEAN type, so your `box.istrigger || Box.size` does not work.

You can change it to

```
if (box.isTrigger || box.size.magnitude < 'the value you need (usually floating point type) ')
```

According to the normal logic, box.isTrigger is a touch, and box.size.magnitude is required to be within a certain range. Then box.size.magnitude must not be greater than a certain range, which is expressed by less than here.

Comment: I can see that `box.size.magnitude < number` gives a boolean, but can you explain how it applies to the OP's logic?

Comment: @Enigmativity Ok, I'll edit it again.

Comment: Sorry, I want to know how it applies to the OP's logic, not yours.